# PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected

Tags: 16.04

I have a new HP Pavilion Gaming Notebook and a new installation of Ubuntu 16.04. When I press Ctrl + Alt + F1 I go start seeing the errors shown in the following image and it doesn't allow me to interact with the console:

[image]

I also see these errors for a while everytime I boot. I need to do Ctrl + Alt + F1 to access a non graphical terminal to install some Nvidia drivers. What's going on?

What's causing the problem seems to be:
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:a115] (rev f1)

```
jpiabrantes@joao:~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1910] (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics [8086:191b] (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem [8086:a131] (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 [8086:a13a] (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a103] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 [8086:a114] (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:a115] (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 [8086:a116] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller [8086:a14e] (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC [8086:a121] (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] [10de:139a] (rev a2)
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 0a)
```

Comment: Could you post the output of :   `  lspci -nn ` . Thanks

Comment: @ankit7540 I've updated my question with that info

Comment: Hey been a long time, same issue with same notebook did you solved it now?

Comment: Yes @Vinz243 the answer bellow solved my problem after all!

Comment: I'm getting this also on Ubuntu 18.04, so this is the bug that keeps giving.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try this,

Use this link ( [about the adding paramter to kernel here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)) to understand about adding kernel boot paramter temporarily and making it permanent.
Then,

Add the parameter ,   `pci=nomsi`

And reboot.

If the problem is solved then make the change permanent. 
If does not work then try,

`pci=noaer`

same way and make it permanent if this works.

(*Reason for appearance is  related to the recent Intel Skylake architecture CPUs and Realtek rtl8723be wireless adaptor.

The ubuntu team knows about it. Read more here [Bug_track_ubuntu_PCIe bus error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173)  )

Comment: Did you try this,  `pci=noaer`  ?

Comment: I had the same problem. Both your solutions worked. I went with `pci=noaer` as this is the first one mentioned in the ubuntu team link you posted. Thanks.

Comment: to make it permanent, use https://askubuntu.com/questions/271058/add-ro-quiet-splash-to-all-entries  *note that there are two similar lines to modify

Comment: I'm using an HP Pavilion 15-ab217ng notebook with Ubuntu 16.04. I had these errors for years and they were driving me nuts. `pci=noaer` worked for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: `pci=noaer` help me on Xubuntu 14.04

Comment: This used to work for me on Ubuntu 16.04, but no longes solves on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Years later this is still an unsolved problem for many devices. Thank you for your solution

Comment: pci=nomsi work with a MSI laptop but the peripherals stop working.
pci=noaer works fine.

Answer (score 18):

Here already answers are provided which also helped me a lot. I use text mode of ubuntu 16.04 and so

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
```

didn't helped me. Here what I changed was -- (in `/etc/default/grub`)

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text pci=nomsi"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

which solved my error(NOTE - I used only `pci=nomsi`, and in case it don't work other option is `pci=noaer`), that may help solve anyone facing the same error.

Comment: Additionally, don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after making changes in the `/etc/default/grub` file to make changes permanent.

Comment: You can edit this file if you boot in recovery mode, drop to terminal, sudo nano the file, then update grup. Then do `reboot`

Answer (score 0):

I always have the same issue when reinstall `Ubuntu 18.04.4` with `ASUS X555UQ Laptop`.

Answers above helped me a lot about adding which parameter to `/etc/default/grub/` but I can't reach terminal (also tty), because after installing OS via live usb, it gives a blank screen(or mentioned issue) instead of login screen.

Then I thought that I have to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time so, according to this link [how to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time), pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> while booting did not cause the GRUB menu to appear. It shows `please select boot device` section for me. Then I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot again and while booting, pressed <kbd>esc</kbd> again. Finally it reached to the GRUB menu and I pressed <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the commands(this page starts with `set params 'Ubuntu'`). Then I added `pci=nomsi` to end of the line starting with `linux` and pressed <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

After this operation, I was able to reach login screen and terminal. Then I followed the [@Ujjal Kumar Das's](https://askubuntu.com/a/926352/829928) answer above and updated my `/etc/default/grub/` file permanently.

Maybe this method works for the users who have the same laptop model like me. I like using Ubuntu, but this issue is so annoying every time.