# How can I avoid this screen in my Xubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: xubuntu

I've installed Xubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Asus notebook

When I'm rebooting it or shutdown my notebook, this screen shows infinitely until I stop it by pressing the power button

[image]

I've tried other distros but I see the same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected](http://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected)

Comment: Please upload the image using the picture button in the question editor and choosing upload so that it can be seen by everyone. I get `Your client does not have permission to get URL…`.