# Steam games crashes randomly on Ubuntu 17.10 (GNOME)

Tags: gnome, games, steam, opengl, 17.10

I have done the switch from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10, but when I downloaded Steam, and opened one game, it crashed after one minute of playing.

I want to mention that it happend on Ubuntu 17.04 as well, but only in TF2.

I've tried many games, and I got the same result, the game freezes, then it has a sound loop, then it crash, but I do not get any error message. (most of them are working on OpenGL)

I have Intel Core i5-6198DU CPU @ 2.30GHz x 4, Intel HD Graphics 510(Skylake GT1), GNOME 3.26.1, 8GB ram, 64-bit.

And I don't have any graphics driver installed.

Can you please tell me what should I do to make it work again? (and please if you want me to post logs and stuff, explain where do I need to find them, because I don't know much about it.)

`journalctl -n 1000` gives me this output https://pastebin.com/gSZNMwK4.

**Important edit: The games don't work in unity, gnome,either on xorg, or wayland session, in fact, after the game crashes I get a messagebox saying report a bug, but nothing happens after I click report.**

Thank you in advance! 
[image]

Comment: Is this under the Wayland based session, or Xorg? If Wayland, perhaps try logging out and switching to the Xorg session, to see if it helps.

Comment: @dobey its not, no matter what session do I use, but thanks for your help:)

Comment: I have a similar problem and had to revert to 17.04. My computer would just self-shutdown with any Steam game requiring my CPU to go in turbo mode, after a while. For games requiring less CPU oomph, the performance would still be far worse than 17.04. This seems to hint that the video drivers / GPU might not be the issue, as I've replicated with a number of Nvidia drivers for my Geforce 1060, but you're on an Intel driver. Maybe try downgrading to 17.04...

Comment: @Mena Thanks for the advice but I dont think so..

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the syslog? (/var/log/syslog)

Comment: @KobiT what do you want me to copy from that file? it is pretty big

Comment: The area around the time the game crashed.

Comment: how can i open the file and copy this information for you, Im pretty noob on all of those stuff :)

Comment: `tail -n 1000 /var/log/syslog` will print the last 1000 lines.
`cat /var/log/syslog` will print the whole file.
Post the area around the time of the crash.

Comment: @KobiT All of the lines are pretty much the same: "Oct 25 23:12:33 gama kernel: [  853.474085] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Oct 25 23:12:33 gama kernel: [  853.474093] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Oct 25 23:12:33 gama kernel: [  853.474102] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)"
again and again

Comment: Enter `lspci` to see which device label belongs to 0000:00:1c.5 This should give the next hint

Comment: @noreabu 00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)

Comment: Please, crash the game, and post the output of `journalctl -n 1000` somewhere on pastebin or a similar site.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I edited my question, please have a look:)

Comment: Well, I don't know, I don't see the stacktrace in journalctf output. Anyway,  try [this solution to some other your errors](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2165261) *(use `apt-get purge` on Ubuntu)*, and I also see something from the game about outdated cache… Try reinstalling the game. If that doesn't help, you may need to find a way to run the game manually from terminal, and provide its output after the crash.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I don't have lm-sensors installed, and as I said before if I switch to unity, the game works perfect! So it can't be something on the cache. And also, I have no idea how to run a game from terminal, but I can look for the logs in the game files if you want

Comment: @Argaman I just don't know if game logs will have the stacktrace. If they do, then fine — stacktrace is the only thing I need so far, although if you see errors before it, it'd nice to have too. That said, I wouldn't put much hope I'll figure out the reason, but a stacktrace could give some hint. To run the game from terminal you have to enter the game installation directory, and then run something of its executables or scripts, possibly with some arguments — what exactly to run depends on the game, and I personally only have Left4Dead2.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I tried to run the game from terminal, but it crashed without having any stacktrace... But anyway the game works fine when I use Unity instead of Gnome, so I don't think its the game's problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to say. I do have in mind some more ideas, like running the game with `gdb`, but it's hard to explain given a variety of possibilities, like if the game ran from a script *(so either gdb have to be attached, or you have to modify a script)*, if the game runs multiple processes *(in which case you might see the game simply quit without a stack, i.e. because another process crashed)* — all of that may involve different actions, commands. I think at this point it's better for you to report a bug to Gnome, and let the devs to figure it out.

Comment: @Hi-Angel thank you very much for all the time you have wasted for me, even if I didn't find a solution yet, you still helped me with some other issues as well :) and I'll try to report the bug.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like there is a problem with a PCI Express device not properly communicating with the Root port. I suspect this may be a kernel issue. You could try using a different kernel, e.g. with: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelPPA

PS: This was meant as a reply to your comment... got the wrong field. Can you maybe update the original question, if this solution is was useful?

Comment: oh man I know how to fix the syslog issue , thats not my problem.  but thank you anyway:) https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected

Comment: lets have a look at the log, when the game is crashing

Comment: I edited my question, but basically are you saying that the cause for the crash is the pci express?

Comment: @Argaman I looked your journalctl, and I see at least a thousand entries every second. I don't know if it's relevant to the crash, but I bet it impacts a performance. If you have means to fix it, I really advice to do so. Regarding the crash: there's no info about it in logs because of the hw-error spam. You can try then running the game from a terminal, and to paste game output in your question. It's just, running a steam game from a terminal require a bit of tackling, like searching its binaries, and maybe some args, as opposed to plain looking `journalctl`… But you can try it too.

Comment: @Hi-Angel but I dont really know how to fix it, I mean I found a solution but I dont know how to do it properly, can you please help me fix the problem with the pci?

Comment: @Argaman just ask on what part are you unsure.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I can't open the grub menu by holding shift, and also what kernel do I need to choose when it will open? Basically I have no idea how to fix this problem at all..

Comment: @Argaman I think you might want to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/142000/266507).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67706/discussion-between-argaman-and-hi-angel).

Comment: @noreabu I have just updated the link now(the output from journalctl), so it might contain more details about the problem