# PCIe bus error severity=corrected id=00e5

Tags: drivers, kernel, asus

It's 2018 year and I found a lot of questions related to it but there's no answers to solve it.

Every time I turn on my laptop I got this error message before the login screen.

[journalctl log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYjBR.png)

I bought this lapton 2 months ago. This is the model: [Asus X541UA](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-Max-X541UA/)

I have tried with several Linux distros, the only one does not show that error was Ubuntu 17.10 Gnome, but I hate Gnome. I need a Ubuntu derived distro for work and I love Kde, so I use either Kubuntu or Kde Neon.

I just installed Kubuntu yesterday, sometimes it does not show the error, but most of the time it does.

`uname -a` output:

`Linux RtPcK 4.13.0-25-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 8 21:14:41 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Some refs I have:

[PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected#771908)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

1. `cp /etc/default/grub ~/Desktop`
2. Edit grub. Add `pci=noaer` at the end of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Line will be like this:

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`
3. `sudo cp ~/Desktop/grub /etc/default/`
4. `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot now

:) Enjoy.