# Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 dual boot, it works for the first time, as soon as I reboot once it won't boot anymore, "PCIe Bus" error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I'm attempting to to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 in a desktop computer with a Windows. I downloaded it and made a bootable USB stick. I then chose the simplest install options and allocated 32 GB of my SSD. Ubuntu then loaded correctly, but, as soon as I rebooted it once, when trying to boot again, it just logs a lot of lines in a white font with a black screen behind. Those lines say:

```
pcieport 0000:00:1d.2: PCIe Bus Error: Security=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
```

Reinstalling Ubuntu works again only once. As soon as I reboot it, I can't boot again.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `grep AER /var/log/syslog*` and `sudo lspci -vt`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I'm temporarily closing this question as I managed to fix it with a brand new install and [following this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected) before it started crashing.

Comment: That's where I was headed... but you should take off that kernel parameter... and run my commands... to see which device (0000:00:1d.2) is generating the errors... and then if there are AER errors in syslog... fix the cause, or use the `pci=noaer` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `grep AER /var/log/syslog*` and `sudo lspci -vt` to determine if you have AER errors, and which device (0000:00:1d.2) is causing them. Fix the cause, or use this...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

Find:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer