# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS freezes after login

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I replaced my windows 10 with Ubuntu on my laptop (Asus X441U) but I'm having some trouble with logging in. The laptop starts up and brings me to log in and once entering my credentials things freeze with a purple screen and no mouse. When I click Ctrl+Alt+F2 at the log in screen, the screen just runs errors and won't stop until I turn off the laptop.

I'm trying to read the errors and believe I see:

```
pcieport 000:00:1c.5:PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type Physical 
Layer, device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000,
[ 0] RxErr
```

This error is thrown non-stop very quickly until I click the power button, which brings me to the loading Ubunutu logo logo loading screen and then shuts off.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected

Comment: When I press and hold shift to start the GRUB menu, the screen goes black and then goes to the log in screen. I'm holding shift the whole time. Any thoughts to get into GRUB?