# OS is not loading due to Bad TLP in Recovery Mode

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, recovery-mode

I am facing some problem in my Ubuntu server (16.04 LTS). All of a sudden, my monitor went black and when I forcefully opened the Grab and try the OS in recovery mode, it is showing Bad TLP with PCIe Bus error and OS is not loading.

[image]

I Also tried quiet splash nomodeset. But it is not working. Adding nomodeset, same PCI Bus error shows.

Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution may be at https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected - try the suggestions there (the accepted answer suggests pci=nomsi).  Otherwise I suggest adding some more details about your hardware to the question.

Comment: Is this a laptop, desktop, or rack mount computer? Edit your question and show me `lspci -nn | grep "1022:1453"`. Same question, different user name?