# Ubuntu 20.04 boot freezes after shutting down the PC, but not after restarting from Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 UEFI. To install it I used the option "Install alongside Windows bootloader". When I boot Ubuntu from the grub after shut down the PC, it freezes, but if I boot Ubuntu from grub after restarting from Windows 10, Ubuntu boots easily and fast enough without any problems.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected)

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Windows, restart and then select Ubuntu. Windows is powering on a device and leaving it powered up when restarting. Ubuntu is not powering up the device.

After starting Ubuntu open a terminal and use `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`.

Locate the line with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Remove `quiet splash` leaving the double quotes and everything else there.

Save the file, exit editor and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now when you start your computer you will see status messages when grub calls Ubuntu. The last status message before computer freezes is the error we need to track down and fix.

---

### Resolution

Upon reviewing boot errors OP discovered problem was a duplicate of:

- [PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected)

Comment: I did what you said. I try to start Ubuntu after the shut down and it shows a long list of errors about pcieport. PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer

Comment: I add a picture with the list of errors in the question

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/771899/1073261 with this I found a way to solve the errors adding the parameter pci=noaer. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Vergs Glad to hear it.