# Xubuntu live-USB install stuck (NO NVIDIA)

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, dell, live-usb

I'm new to Linux, Trying to install xubuntu 20.04 on a dell inspiron 11-3000 series (2.3MGz, 8RAM, only intell GPU) which already runs windows 10, using a bootable-USB created with RUFUS. Bios options configured to boot USB first, disable secure boot, disable fast boot, as these cause problems for other users.

My problem: When xubuntu boot starts **in UEFI mode**, no matter what I choose in the xubuntu GRUB menu, (try w/o install, or install) installation **gets stuck** while loading one of the **first install-configs**. While stuck, mouse turns to loading symbol, clicking continue and waiting for 2 hours does nothing. Weirdly enough, I can never make it past the "select installation mode" page. If I take too long on the language, keyboard or wifi config pages, i can get stuck on any of those (as if it was a time/memory related problem). If I choose the **legacy option** in BIOS, i don't go through the GRUB menu, but installation stucks just the same, while loading one of the first 5 install-config pages, dependending only on how fast I go through them. **This problem must be caused by my computer, because the installation process fails for xubuntu 20.04, 18.04, and also failed with ubuntu 18.04,** but i have no idea of where to look for the problem's cause.

When the installation loading stucks, the power button triggers a black screen with fast code lines repetitively describing an error. After a while, this ends and a message to "remove USB and press enter" appears, which leads me back to BIOS config or windows.

I've been recommended to check file integrity, but the filecheck takes place automatically on every booting attempt while xUbuntu loads, without errors. I've also tried a solution recommended for Nvidia-related bugs, (in the GRUB, changing a code line in install option from "quiet splash" to "nomodeset"), which changed nothing. I recently reset my computer to factory settings to avoid, to try a fresh start, but accomplished nothing.

This seems to be the case for many other stackExchange users with low impact questions, so if there's an obvious way to fix this i'll be more than glad to get any indication of how to go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reply and solution to the "pcireport" problem allowed me to install through the BIOS-managed drive boot. It wasn't a imaginary windows block, but rather a strange processor optimization option. It's still weird that I was able to bypass this problem through the "windows USB system restoration", but what works just works i guess.

https://askubuntu.com/a/771908/1082007

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and I'll share it in hopes of helping anyone with the same dumb problem: 
Apparently, trying to directly boot the live USB drive from the BIOS menu wasn't working, no matter which Xubuntu version I chose. What did work and allowed me to proceed with the whole installation process was the **Windows 10 restoration option to boot from a live drive**.

I can only assume Windows had a weird regulation (maybe for security) to avoid direct BIOS-managed drive boots, however I haven't found out how or why this happens, so I guess it's still an open question.

*Happily replying from Xubuntu 18.04*