# Impossible to install kubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu, uefi

I have a success first time to install kubuntu 20.04 but after reboot I have some problem

**KUBUNTU INSTALLED but not start**

1-  After American megatrend logo :

```
 Xsession:warning:unable to write to /tmp, X session may exit with an error
    Impossible to click okay, click on shutdown button and Kubuntu start
    CTRL ALT F3
    see loop pcieport 0000:00:1b.5: AER PCIdevice ERROR: .... status=Corrected ==> difficult to read the line too fast
    shutdown applied automacally
```

**Reinstall Kubuntu**

2 - Start usb key boot and choose UEFI: SMI USB DISK 1100

3 - Start Kubuntu

5 - Choose language French and Install Kubuntu

6 - choose french keyboard

7 - netwok - no

8 - Normal installation

9 - Setting disk configuration ===> Wait do not work

10 - CTRL ALT F3

```
loop in pcieport 0000:00:1b.5: AER PCIdevice ERROR: .... status=Corrected ==> difficult to read the line too fast
```

11 - stop the machine

12 - restart  with usb key ans **ESC until go to grub**

13 - cat (hd0,gpt4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg
==> see the file

No idea to edit and change inside ===> Could help me to resolve this problem ?

look a post as this : [PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected)

First time for me to work with grub, do not understand well :

how to edit a file ad grup.cfg

how to make something for tmp and remove the file inside for example or inside the log system

Lost need someone can help me and guide me to resolve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: You're getting errors during the installation itself?  Are you sure that your installation media is valid?

Comment: Yes during the installation It stop on the disk setup. and create errors above. No possible to format the disk. If can do that I can restart with a clean install

Comment: *"No possible to format the disk"* - can you elaborate on this? If your installation media is valid - your problem likely has to do with whatever is already on your PC.  If you are trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows - have you looked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: Because for me it^'s impossible to go the next step hard disk configuration. Originally, Kubuntu has been installed via the UEFI windows settings not directly by the bios option (usb selection).

Comment: Have you tried formatting your disk *before* starting the installer?  You can do this easily with the "Disks" app in a live session ("Try Ubuntu")

Comment: I make reformat and create a linuxswap and / . But the problem is always the same. The loop appear and the computer is very slow in reaction .pcieport 0000:00......
Impossible to continue correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution :

- First reinstall windows
- Reinstall Kubuntu
- Create an EFI partition

Works fine now