# Errors upon start up of Ubuntu

Tags: pcie

When I start up Ubuntu I get the following error and then it carries on booting up as normal. Does anyone know why I get this and how to fix it please ? I have Intel i7 10700 and I have ROG STRIX B460-H ASUS motherboard.

The error starts of with PCIe Bus Error: severity=corrected

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: 80 plus people have solved this error with the answer here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected

Comment: Thank you. This resolved my issue. How do I set this thread to SOLVED ?

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question with the link I provided. If I remember correctly all I did was search Ask Ubuntu with your error message you will be able to accept your own answer in a day or two