# Battery drops in chunks and too fast, also for charging

Tags: battery

I bought this laptop last month, the battery percentage goes from 100% to 81% after a few minutes (like 4 or less) for example and without passing through other values, and then goes on, from 81% to 63% and to 43%... and in a few minutes the computer shuts down.

I'm having some PCIe errors on shutdown and sometimes on bootup, tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected), but didn't work, I don't know if that's related.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I'll try to let it drops the whole battery.

I can run commands to show the stats of the computer I just don't know them, please comment which I can use.

Other things happening but maybe not related is that I can't get the thouchpad buttons working (even changing the new Ubuntu touchpad settings) neither the headphones are automatic detected, if this does not help, just ignore it, the battery is more important now.

Comment: If it is a really old thick laptop, this is normal. Did it have behaivior like this short after you started using the laptop?

Comment: Indeed, sounds like a failing battery. If new, your warranty should cover it.

Comment: As soon as the laptop starts this starts to happen, and it is new, I bought it last month, I don't know if I have the warranty anymore because I updated to a ssd