# boot stops at PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, kernel, pci

I was trying to update libpango because another program needed an updated one, for that I removed older one after which my pc froze and this issue started occuring.

I am using ubuntu 20.04, I have checked and tried some things such as [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2400299) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/771908/732903).

The image of the error:
[image: boot error messages]

After this, the boot stops, the only thing i can do is reboot by Ctrl+alt+del.

My log files are all only a few MBs.
In recovery mode, I have tried fixing broken packages, etc. When i continue normal boot from recovery mode, I get a text login (no GUI) and after that, the terminal (bash terminal, not grub). I have updated grub from there and also ran `sudo apt install linux-image-generic` but I still get this issue. I have a dual boot with windows 10.

Edit: The output of `lspci -nn`, `lspci -tv` and `lshw -C network`
[image]

[image]

Edit2: `uname -r` = `5.8.0-50-generic`
output of `ls -alh /boot` (I used -alh to keep sizes in better format, sorry this one is an image as well)
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `lspci -nn` and `lspci -tv` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I have edited the question with outputs of those three commands

Comment: It's your wireless card. Have you tried adding `pci=noaer` to /etc/default/grub and then `sudo update-grub`? Your first screenshot is necessary, but the new screenshots should be text that you copy/paste from your terminal window. Edit your question and show me `uname -r` and `ls -al /boot`.

Comment: @heynnema as I mentioned, after going through recovery mode, I don't get a gui or mouse/cursor, just the terminal (after user login). So copy pasting it is not possible. What I can do is save those outputs to a file and store it in a location shared with other OS if it's necessary. I have tried pci=noaer in boot parameters (it's temporary), it doesn't show the text but still doesn't boot.

Comment: Ah, ok... silly me. Go ahead and show me the last two commands.

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop computer?

Comment: @heynnema I have added outputs for the last two commands, this is a laptop

Comment: Get to the GRUB menu, choose Advanced Options, and select the -49 kernel, and see if  that boots. If not, select the older -72 kernel and see if that boots. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema they have the same issue

Comment: Do you have a Ubuntu Live USB? If so, see if it boots.

Comment: Yes, i tried the live usb, that boots up fine

Comment: When you boot to the Ubuntu Live USB, does the wireless work?

Comment: Do you have Windows? Does it boot?

Comment: yes, it works. My windows also boots properly. I plan on creating a repair disk for ubuntu if i don't find any other solution, do you think that'll work?

Comment: The only Ubuntu repair disk is the Ubuntu Live USB. Just on an outside chance, let's check your Ubuntu file system. Give me a couple of minutes to put together instructions for you... report back.

Comment: Do you have good backups?

Comment: Yes, I backed up all necessary files in the windows partition (no system backups if that's what you mean, due to storage issues, but i saved everything imp), i'll update you with live usb results in ~5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lspci -nn` and `lspci -tv` shows the problem is with the wireless card. Adding `pci=noaer` to /etc/default/grub, and `sudo update-grub` did not fix or work around the problem. Booting to older kernels does not help. Computer will still not fully boot up.

Let's check your Ubuntu file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Ubuntu Live USB boots fine.

`fsck` found inode problems, and fixed them, but the computer still doesn't boot.

Reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: It prompted a few things similar to `Inode 262523 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter/narrower. Optimize<y>?` to which I responded with yes, after 5 passes, it displayed `*** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED***` and 55xxx/21yyy files and 76xxx/87yyy blocks. After reboot, the installed one still had same issue

Comment: @SajanGohil Although there still may be a hardware problem, go ahead and reinstall Ubuntu. The installer will recognize the previous Ubuntu installation. Look closely during the first part of the install setup, and if you see a tiny tiny box that says "Format", uncheck it, and it **should** leave your /home folder alone.