# PCIe Bus Error with Killer Ethernet

Tags: drivers, kernel, ethernet

I have the following ethernet controller in my laptop

```
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

and I keep getting these warnings in my `journalctl -xe` output

```
Nov 30 05:22:55 laptonix kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Nov 30 05:22:55 laptonix kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0:   device [1969:e0b1] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
Nov 30 05:22:55 laptonix kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0:    [ 7] BadDLLP               
Nov 30 05:22:56 laptonix kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:08:00.0
Nov 30 05:22:56 laptonix kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Receiver ID)
Nov 30 05:22:56 laptonix kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0:   device [1969:e0b1] error status/mask=00000040/00002000
Nov 30 05:22:56 laptonix kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0:    [ 6] BadTLP
```

the above messages keep spamming with occasional error messages like

```
Nov 30 05:23:15 laptonix kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=143095 end=143096) time 1792 us, min 1062, max 1079, scanline start 962, end 60
```

I am using **Kubuntu 21.10** with kernel version **5.13.0-21-generic** also tested with 21.04 on live usb and had the same messages.

I have read many solutions revolving around adding to kernel boot `pci=nomsi` or `pci=noaer` or `pcie_aspm=off` but none of these worked for me.

Is this a bug in the kernel or is there something I can do to stop these messages from appearing in the logs?

The output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` is `V1.12` which is the latest available and the laptop is Acer Predator Helios 300 PH315-52

EDIT:

the output of `lspci -nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:3ec4] (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] [8086:3e9b]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller [8086:a379] (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:a36d] (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM [8086:a36f] (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:a370] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a368] (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:a369] (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller [8086:a360] (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller [8086:a353] (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #21 [8086:a32c] (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a330] (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13 [8086:a334] (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller [8086:a30d] (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:a323] (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller [8086:a324] (rev 10)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] [10de:2191] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1aeb] (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller [10de:1aec] (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB Type-C UCSI Controller [10de:1aed] (rev a1)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Kingston Technology Company, Inc. U-SNS8154P3 NVMe SSD [2646:5008] (rev 01)
07:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Phison Electronics Corporation E16 PCIe4 NVMe Controller [1987:5016] (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0b1] (rev 10)
```

the output of `lspci -tv`

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-01.0-[01-05]--+-00.0  NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile]
           |               +-00.1  NVIDIA Corporation TU116 High Definition Audio Controller
           |               +-00.2  NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB 3.1 Host Controller
           |               \-00.3  NVIDIA Corporation TU116 USB Type-C UCSI Controller
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
           +-04.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
           +-08.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
           +-12.0  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
           +-14.3  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
           +-15.1  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller
           +-1b.0-[06]----00.0  Kingston Technology Company, Inc. U-SNS8154P3 NVMe SSD
           +-1d.0-[07]----00.0  Phison Electronics Corporation E16 PCIe4 NVMe Controller
           +-1d.4-[08]----00.0  Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
           +-1f.4  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
           \-1f.5  Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller
```

the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Cannon Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 10
       serial: a8:6d:aa:e7:91:f4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-21-generic firmware=46.6b541b68.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b4618000-b461bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 10
       serial: 7c:d3:0a:80:eb:d6
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.13.0-21-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:b4300000-b433ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

Comment: Two questions: (0) is the computer overclocked in any fashion? (1) has the latest firmware packages for the notebook been installed?

Comment: (0) not that I know of
(1) yes

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I edited the question to add the information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected)

Comment: @nobody No, I did try the solutions mentioned but nothing worked.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `lspci -nn` and `lspci -tv`.

Comment: any thing in bios or uefi for powermanagement?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

Find:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Change it to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

Save the file.

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Comment: I have already tried that as I stated in my question `pci=noaer` did not make any difference.

Comment: @Farahats9 Did you `update-grub` and `reboot`? And show me the `lspci` commands that I requested?

Comment: yes I do `update-grub` and `reboot` and I added the output of the commands as you requested, thanks a lot for trying to help.

Comment: @Farahats9 Do you connect via wireless or wired connection? Show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: I am connected via wireless network and nothing connected on the ethernet port, edited the question with the details

Comment: @Farahats9 Ah! Do you have **anything** that you can connect to the ethernet port, and then see if the AER errors change, or go away?

Comment: I made a test by connecting to the router via wire the errors were the same. turning off wifi and disconnecting the wire stopped all errors. in summary if either wifi or ethernet has connection it shows the error.

Comment: @Farahats9 I'm sorry... but I guess that I don't have an answer for you.