# After upgrade to ubuntu 22.04.01 kern.log and syslog files full of the same error

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

after upgrading from ubuntu 20 to ubuntu 22.04.01, my kern.log and syslog files become massive (20Gb+) and they have the same error over and over again.

**kern.log file**

```
Aug 27 14:32:24 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  644.328754] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Aug 27 14:32:24 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  644.328770] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 27 14:32:24 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  644.328776] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [144d:a804] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
Aug 27 14:32:24 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  644.328784] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 27 14:32:26 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  645.451640] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Aug 27 14:32:26 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  645.451651] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 27 14:32:26 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  645.451653] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [144d:a804] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
Aug 27 14:32:26 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  645.451655] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr
```

**syslog file**

```
Aug 27 14:33:18 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  697.703411] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Aug 27 14:33:18 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  697.703421] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 27 14:33:18 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  697.703426] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [144d:a804] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
Aug 27 14:33:18 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  697.703431] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Aug 27 14:33:18 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  698.331855] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Aug 27 14:33:18 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  698.331864] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Aug 27 14:33:18 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  698.331866] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [144d:a804] error status/mask=00000001/00006000
Aug 27 14:33:18 dainius-XPS-15-9560 kernel: [  698.331869] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr
```

At this point, from time to time, I have to remove the content of these files, because they eat up all of my storage. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected

Comment: also see: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1819025#p1819025

Comment: @DainiusPreimantas try checking lspci for which device has that ID

Comment: @Esther It looks like the NVMe SSD controller:
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961/SM963 [144d:a804]